# drag and drop images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm newbie at jquery and I'm trying to develop a game for kids that work with drag and drop images in specific zones.It's the same as this card game in this url: http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html
I tried to understand its source code but I can't change the cards with images in this part of code :

```
    // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }



     // Create the card slots
      var words = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten' ];
      for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
        $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
          accept: '#cardPile div',
          hoverClass: 'hovered',
          drop: handleCardDrop
        } );
      }

    }
```

The whole description of the source code is here :http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

I'm waiting for your help please and thanks in advance

Comment: You question is not clear "but I can't change the cards with images". What is the specific problem?

Comment: The cards that he has used them are only a div elements styled with css I want to replace those elements(cards) with draggable images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong then you want to set image of all the cards which you are utilizing in game.

Then you just have to set background image of all the cards in css like
take example of card 1 so its id is card1 then set its css as following

```css
#card1{
background-image:url("http://static3.bigstockphoto.com/thumbs/7/0/3/large2/30774275.jpg");
}
```

Comment: sorry I tried to change the card's background  but it's not working.

Comment: I didn't see your link for the demo now it's clear and it's working.thnks a lot bro

Comment: jsfiddle.net/bhavik15vora/4su3j4ca